# Why beforeRouteUpdate not working when I return to first page?

Tags: vue.js, vue-router

I have component with paginator. In this component I have *beforeRouteEnter* and *beforeRouteUpdate* for fetching data.
I open in browser http://localhost:8080/#/pages/1 After this I click by links *.../pages/2* *.../pages/3* and beforeRouteUpdate fetching data and show that. When I click to link *.../pages/1* (it first path, beforeRouteEnter worked with him) browser go to this link, but beforeRouteUpdate does not occur and I see data of old page

code of my router:

```
export default new Router({
  mode: 'hash',
  linkActiveClass: 'open active',
  scrollBehavior: () => ({ y: 0 }),
  routes: [{
    path: '/',
    redirect: '/pages/1',
    name: 'Home',
    component: Full,
    children: [{
      path: 'pages/:num?',
      name: 'Pages',
      component: Pages
    }, {
      path: 'pageForm/:id?',
      name: 'PageForm',
      component: PageForm
    }, {
      path: 'settings',
      name: 'Settings',
      component: Settings
    }]
  }]
})
```

How I can resolve this issue?

**UPD:**

in App.vue and Full.vue I replace

```
 <router-view></router-view>
```

to

```
      <transition>
        <keep-alive>
          <router-view></router-view>
        </keep-alive>  
      </transition>
```

but it not worked for me

**UPD2**

I make in App.vue

```
<keep-alive include="full">
  <router-view></router-view>
</keep-alive>
```

and in Full.vue

```
<keep-alive include="Pages">
  <router-view></router-view>
</keep-alive>
```

but it not worked for me too

Answer (score 0):

Your components are cached by vue. So, you need to use [keep-alive](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#keep-alive). This will keep your component fresh and it will not allow to render component from cache.

Note:

> When a component is toggled inside , its activated and deactivated lifecycle hooks will be invoked accordingly.
>
> `<keep-alive>` does not work with functional components because they do not have instances to be cached.

Comment: Bhojendra Nepal, thanks! I use https://github.com/mrholek/coreui-free-vue-admin-template as base for my app. I not understand how use keep-alive. In all places I have only router-view

Answer (score 0):

My error was in my code. I not call next() in beforeRouteUpdate.
Now all working good